# Subsequent conditional formatting based on value between two input values - formula to search

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, vba

The only thing I need to modify is the formula listed below.  I've modified the code to apply conditional formatting to any cell values within my range that fall between two values (Input Values 1 & 2).  So for example - if I am searching for any cell values that are between 20,000 and 50,000, it would change the font color of those cells to red and bold. The next part of the coding uses the formula to then apply conditional formatting on the cells in Column G.

Can I somehow modify the formula below so that it find any values that are greater than or equal to Input Value 1 BUT less than or equal to Input Value 2 within the specified range?  The formula currently searches for only the exact value of Value 1.

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & Chr(34) & Value1 & Chr(34) & ",""&AB1&"",""&AG1&"",""&AL1&"",""&AQ1))"
```

Below I've cut and pasted my code

```
Sub Between_Values()

Dim Value1 As String
Dim Value2 As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim myFormula As String

Value1 = InputBox("Between This amount  (enter lowest contract amount)")
Value2 = InputBox("And This amount  (enter highest contract amount)")

Set myRange = Range("G:G,AB:AB,AG:AG,AL:AL,AQ:AQ")

myRange.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
myRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
Formula1:="=" & Value1, Formula2:="=" & Value2
  myRange.FormatConditions(myRange.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With myRange.FormatConditions(1).Font
  .Italic = False
  .Bold = True
  .Color = 255
  .TintAndShade = 0
 End With

myFormula = "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & Chr(34) & Value1 & Chr(34) & ",""&AB1&"",""&AG1&"",""&AL1&"",""&AQ1))"

Columns("G:G").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=myFormula
Columns("G:G").FormatConditions(Columns("G:G").FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Columns("G:G").FormatConditions(1).Font
     .Bold = True
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
 Columns("G:G").FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea would be to loop through the range and format the current cell anytime it fits those criteria

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In myRange .Cells
    If cel.value >= Value1 And cel.value <= Value2 Then
        With cel
            'do formatting
        End With
    End If
Next cel
```